# Keeping column labels when using the select function with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm combining several datasets and keeping only specific columns, however, when I use the select function from dplyr, it does not retain the original column labels (in my case, the item text).

After I import the data, I use the following code to select the variables I'd like to keep:

```
Wave1Data_Clean <- select(Wave1Data, ID, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
```

When I do this, the column names are correct as are the values, however, the column labels are replaced with the labels of the original dataframe. For example, if column #1's label was 'location' in the original data, the column name for the ID in the df would be 'location' instead of the label associated with ID.

Is there a way to retain the appropriate column labels?

Comment: Are you referring to labels like metadata (e.g. SPSS labels) that get stored as column atributes if you use packages like haven to read the data?

Comment: Yes, I'm importing .sav files that have the 'item text' as the labels. That is what I'm trying to retain.

Comment: @akrun Here is a small example. 

Using this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h7bwyfhngmtk58k/Example.sav?dl=0)

`library(dplyr)
setwd("~/Desktop/")

Example <- read.spss("Example.sav",use.value.label=FALSE, to.data.frame=TRUE)
Example_Clean <- select(Example, ID, X1, X2, X3, X4,X5)`

You'll see that the labels in the new df retain the order from the original df

Comment: @ClaudiuPapasteri - sorry, didn't tag you earlier

Answer (score 2):

I can see the problem you describe when I view the data frame in RStudio.

[Example_Clean in RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C43m4.png)

I'm not sure why the labels get mixed up, but you can overwrite them with the correct labels.

Assuming that you're using `read.spss` from the `foreign` package, the labels are stored as an attribute called "variable.labels". You can access the labels using:

```
attr(Example_Clean, "variable.labels")
```

The following code overwrites the labels with the correct ones.

```
var_labs <- attr(Example_Clean, "variable.labels")
var_labs <- var_labs[names(Example_Clean)]
attr(Example_Clean, "variable.labels") <- var_labs
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of dplyr (1.0.5), the attribute "variable.labels" is lost entirely when using `dplyr::select()`. It seems that a better way to store column labels is to have attributes associated to the vectors themselves rather than the whole dataframe, which is what functions from the haven package do. Using `haven::read_sav()` as an alternative will keep the labels when transforming the data.

Here is a reproducible comparison:

```r
library(foreign)
# import example SAV from foreign
sav <- system.file("files", "electric.sav", package = "foreign")
dat_for <- read.spss(file = sav, to.data.frame = TRUE)

# labels are saved as a variable.labels attribute for the whole dataframe
str(dat_for)
#> 'data.frame':    240 obs. of  13 variables:
#>  $ CASEID  : num  13 30 53 84 89 102 117 132 151 153 ...
#>  $ FIRSTCHD: Factor w/ 5 levels "NO CHD","SUDDEN  DEATH",..: 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 2 ...
#>  $ AGE     : num  40 49 43 50 43 50 45 47 53 49 ...
#>  $ DBP58   : num  70 87 89 105 110 88 70 79 102 99 ...
#>  $ EDUYR   : num  16 11 12 8 NA 8 NA 9 12 14 ...
#>  $ CHOL58  : num  321 246 262 275 301 261 212 372 216 251 ...
#>  $ CGT58   : num  0 60 0 15 25 30 0 30 0 10 ...
#>  $ HT58    : num  68.8 72.2 69 62.5 68 68 66.5 67 67 64.3 ...
#>  $ WT58    : num  190 204 162 152 148 142 196 193 172 162 ...
#>  $ DAYOFWK : Factor w/ 7 levels "SUNDAY","MONDAY",..: NA 5 7 4 2 1 NA 1 3 5 ...
#>  $ VITAL10 : Factor w/ 2 levels "ALIVE","DEAD": 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 ...
#>  $ FAMHXCVR: Factor w/ 2 levels "NO","YES": 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
#>  $ CHD     : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  - attr(*, "variable.labels")= Named chr [1:13] "CASE IDENTIFICATION NUMBER" "FIRST CHD EVENT" "AGE AT ENTRY" "AVERAGE DIAST BLOOD PRESSURE 58" ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:13] "CASEID" "FIRSTCHD" "AGE" "DBP58" ...

# dplyr::select() loses the variable.labels attribute:
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
dat_for %>% select(1:2) %>% str()
#> 'data.frame':    240 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ CASEID  : num  13 30 53 84 89 102 117 132 151 153 ...
#>  $ FIRSTCHD: Factor w/ 5 levels "NO CHD","SUDDEN  DEATH",..: 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 2 ...

# but to be fair, base slicing also loses the attribute:
dat_for[,1:2] %>% str()
#> 'data.frame':    240 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ CASEID  : num  13 30 53 84 89 102 117 132 151 153 ...
#>  $ FIRSTCHD: Factor w/ 5 levels "NO CHD","SUDDEN  DEATH",..: 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 2 ...

# import same file with haven
library(haven)
dat_hav <- read_sav(file = sav)

# labels are attributes of columns
str(dat_hav$CASEID)
#>  num [1:240] 13 30 53 84 89 102 117 132 151 153 ...
#>  - attr(*, "label")= chr "CASE IDENTIFICATION NUMBER"
#>  - attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F4.0"
#>  - attr(*, "display_width")= int 0

# dplyr::select() keeps them
dat_hav %>% select(1:2) %>% str()
#> tibble[,2] [240 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ CASEID  : num [1:240] 13 30 53 84 89 102 117 132 151 153 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "CASE IDENTIFICATION NUMBER"
#>   ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F4.0"
#>   ..- attr(*, "display_width")= int 0
#>  $ FIRSTCHD: dbl+lbl [1:240] 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 6, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...
#>    ..@ label        : chr "FIRST CHD EVENT"
#>    ..@ format.spss  : chr "F1.0"
#>    ..@ display_width: int 0
#>    ..@ labels       : Named num [1:5] 1 2 3 5 6
#>    .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "NO CHD" "SUDDEN  DEATH" "NONFATALMI" "FATAL   MI" ...
#>  - attr(*, "label")= chr "                       SPSS/PC+"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>